# PHP DateTime year/week/day bug with 1st january 2022

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm maintening a php app with a planning that get day event via Year, week number and day number of the week.
This first january of 2022 cause me problem... Here is why:

---

- When I get 2021-12-31 data

```php
$thirtyOne = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2021-12-31');
dump($thirtyOne);
dump('Year: '.$thirtyOne->format('Y').' Week: '.$thirtyOne->format('W').' Day:'.$thirtyOne->format('N'));
```

It returns

```php
Test.php on line 22:
DateTime @1640953850 {#2023 ▼
  date: 2021-12-31 13:30:50.0 Europe/Paris (+01:00)
}

Test.php on line 23:
"Year: 2021 Week: 52 Day:5"
```

---

- When I get 2022-01-01 data

```php
$first = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2022-01-01');
dump($first);
dump('Year: '.$first->format('Y').' Week: '.$first->format('W').' Day:'.$first->format('N'));
```

It returns

```php
Test.php on line 26:
DateTime @1641040250 {#2029 ▼
  date: 2022-01-01 13:30:50.0 Europe/Paris (+01:00)
}

Test.php on line 27:
"Year: 2022 Week: 52 Day:6"
```

The problem is that for php, saturday first january of 2022 is the 6th day (good) of the 52th week (good) of... 2022 (not good).

So if I try to get this date with these data

```php
$getFirst  = new \DateTime();
$getFirst = $getFirst->setISODate('2022', '52', '6');
dump($getFirst);
```

It returns

```php
Test.php on line 31:
DateTime @1672489850 {#2036 ▼
  date: 2022-12-31 13:30:50.527037 Europe/Paris (+01:00)
}
```

To get the good day, I have to modify the year to 2021

```php
$getFirst  = new \DateTime();
$getFirst = $getFirst->setISODate('2021', '52', '6');
dump($getFirst);
```

That returns

```php
Test.php on line 35:
DateTime @1641040250 {#2045 ▼
  date: 2022-01-01 13:30:50.527108 Europe/Paris (+01:00)
}
```

Is this problem known ?

Comment: Not a bug, it's by design. `Week number according to the ISO-8601 standard, weeks starting on Monday. The first week of the year is the week that contains that year's first Thursday (='First 4-day week'). ISO representation: 2022-W01` - https://www.epochconverter.com/weeknumbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:
`$ww  =  date('o');` to get the year according to workweek.

`o   ISO 8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead.`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

In your example:

```
$first = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2022-01-01');
dump($first);
dump('Year: '.$first->format('o').' Week: '.$first->format('W').' Day:'.$first->format('N'));
```

will get:

`..."Year: 2021 Week: 52 Day:6"`